# set GestureListener on Layout or FlipperView

Tags: android

How do I set my gesture listener to my linearlayout only or flipperview? Because I have a FlipperView that flips but I dont want it to flip when i swipe/fling on any part of the screen, I only want to execute the flipping when I fling/swipe on the layout or on the part of the FlipperView. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// you can use onTouch Listner instead of Gesture

```
yourLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

   Log.e("HIGHT CLICk!!"+ event.getY(), "-----------"+event.getX());

    if((26<event.getX() && event.getX()<120) && (25<event.getY()&&event.getY()<120)){

//do your actions here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Padma Kumar's answer is right.
I made a custom FlippView with auto flip and fliing gesture. [ViewFlipper](https://github.com/xinanadu/ViewFlipper), I'd like to share it.